# Bluebirdjs swallowing errors when binded to 'this'

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

Taking the following example:

```
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', function(e) {
  console.error(e);
});

var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  console.log('start');
  resolve();
});

p.bind(this).then(function() {
  console.log('then');
  //this.callfunction here
  throw new Error('err');
});
```

I expect the error to be caught in the unhandledrejection event listener and the error is outputted to console. This works fine when `.bind(this)` is not in the code but the error seems to be swallowed when used. Any explanation as to why this is the case would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like [bug 841](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/841). Are you using a recent version?

Comment: yeah, thanks for the reply. I was using an older version (3.0.5). Bumped it to a later version and it works